# How to show only published node in Drupal Facets (Facet API + Search API)?

Tags: search

I have some taxonomies and node belongs to these when i have created search with facet then all node displaying(publishe + unpublish). i want only published node will show.

Answer (score 4):

You need to click the "Filters" tab in your search API index, then check the  "Exclude unpublished nodes" option.

Answer (score 0):

- Try with re indexing all your site content once or run the site cron
- Did you try with the search api query alter hooks,

> ```
> function yourmodule_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
>   $info = entity_get_info($index->item_type);
>   $query->condition($info['schema_fields_sql']['base table'], 6, '=');
> }
> ```